# sendip IPv6 ICMP ff02::16

Tags: nfs, switch, ipv6, tftp, bootp

I would like to send the following packet out with the `sendip` program (or any other program):

```
IPv6, destination address: FF02::16, source address: (mine)
ICMPv6, type: 143 (Multicast Listener Report Message v2)
```

The complete packet recorded with tcpdump:
[image: ICMPv6 package capture]

You may ask why I would like to send out this packet?
Because raspberry pi network boot does not start on my switch (tried out two model: TP-Link TL-SG1008P, TP-Link TL-SF1008P), unless
this packet is sent out with an independent computer.

I send out the above packet with an another raspberry pi, by constantly rebooting into the desktop, the ip address is received via DHCP.
Also if I plug my laptop into this LAN, my laptop also send out this packet (ubuntu 18.04, networkmanager, dhcp).

Once this packet hits the switch, the network boot is initiated and the Raspberry pi is able to boot via TFTP, and nfs.

The complete setup is made with 9 raspberry pi (network boot is enabled), and a master raspberry pi, which acts as nfs server, tftp server and dhcp server.

The whole boot process is cumbersome because I need one raspberry pi with an SD card which I boot manually, or my laptop which I unplug and replug to initiate the whole boot process.

Once this packet hits the switch all the 8 raspberry pi starting to boot via tftp/nfs, and boots up fine.

I want to periodically send out the above packet, to make the whole process seamless. I suspect it is a bug in the switch.

This is how I tried:

`$ sendip -p ipv6  -p icmp -cd 3 ff02::16:
Couldn't get destination host: gethostbyname2(): Success`

The local LAN, where everything is connected is on IPv4, 192.168.0.x.
So I only need this one IPv6 packet to avoid a switch bug.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to specify the destination address as an argument to ipv6 module, e.g. `sendip -p ipv6 -6d ff02::16:  -p icmp -cd 3 localhost` hoping that module option has the priority over the `hostname` argument?

Comment: `sudo sendip -p ipv6 -6d   ff02::16: -p icmp -ct 143 fe80::a0a9:dd22:8af:2b9a`, where `fe..9a` is the ipv6 address of my network card. No package going out.

Comment: You've forgotten the scope ID.